# Python best way to read data from multiple classes and link into object of main class

Tags: python

import cx_Oracle
from cx_Oracle import DatabaseError

class DBconnection:
    def **init**(self, credentials):
        self.connectionString = ''
        self.credentials = credentials
        self.msg = ''

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "<DBConnection: {} on '{}'>".format(self.msg, self.credentials)

def connect_db(self):
    try:
        self.connectionString = cx_Oracle.connect(self.credentials)
    except DatabaseError:
        self.msg = "Error TNS: no listener"
    else:
        self.msg = "Connection Successful"
```

Comment: what was the question?

Comment: Hi, Please suggest best way to implement above code. This is a class DBConnection having __init__() method and these two methods which connect Oracle DB. I can run this by creating object of this and print object. But I want to call this into different class DataReader where we make connection with Oracle and read data. Here we are passing connection string into __init__() of this class. What is the best way to implement such scenario as I can't create object into other class definition and pass string into init method and then connect with method connect_db?

Comment: Apologies, I know it's not clear. The above class is executable perfectly when I create a object of DBconnection and pass credentials into init.

Comment: Apologies, I know it's not clear. The above class is executable perfectly when I create a object of DBconnection and pass credentials into init. What if I want to call this class from other class, DataReader, how can I create object there, and pass credentials into init? My logic is to make connection in 2nd class, and then read data using sql queries in DataReader. I can do connection in this but want to keep in different class. Should I create classmethod in DB connection? What changes I can do? How to implement such scenario? Please help.

Comment: Could you please edit your question so that it is clearer what you are asking without needing to go through the comments? I'll provide you with an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is called composition. Just google "python composition" and you'll find plenty of examples and best practices. There are many different ways this can be done. I'll give you two small examples here:

You could compose the dependency between the class by hard-coding the dependency, as follows:

```
# example classes
import cx_Oracle

class DBConnector():
    def __init__(self, credentials):
        self.credentials = credentials

    def connect(self):
        return cx_Oracle.connect(self.credentials)

class DataReader():
    def __init__(self, credentials):
        self.connector = DBConnector(credentials)

# run example
credentials = {
    "server": "my_server",
    "port": 123,
    "database": "my_db"
}

my_reader = DataReader(credentials)
connection = my_reader.connector.connect()
```

You could however also *inject* the dependency. This is called "dependency injection" if you want to read up on why its cool - but essentially it boils down to the fact that you could create many different DBConnector classes and DataReader will be able to use them (for example, you might create a second class DBConnectorMySQL that connects to MySQL instead of oracle). You could do this as follows:

```
# example classes
class DBConnector():
    def __init__(self, credentials):
        self.credentials = credentials

    def connect(self):
        return cx_Oracle.connect(self.credentials)


class DataReader():
    def __init__(self, connector):
        self.connector = connector

# run example
credentials = {
    "server": "my_server",
    "port": 123,
    "database": "my_db"
}

connector = DBConnector(credentials)
my_reader = DataReader(connector)
connection = my_reader.connector.connect()
```

Comment: Thanks Karl, this is superb. In fact 1st solution code is what I am looking for. I am new to OOPs and would like to apply better techniques of writing code. want to have separate class for each task and use whatever is needed but missing the concepts of using all together. Would you please share any web url or document/book which helps me to understand how to write better code?

Comment: Hard to say. I learnt these principles a long time ago, so I'm not really up to date on the most recent sources. You could try something like this though: https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Object_Oriented_Programming.html. Or do some google searches for "python object oriented programming", "python functional programming", "python design patterns"